# loopback embedsone relation exclude some property fields like password

Tags: loopbackjs, relation, loopback

I have an **embedsone** relationship. It embeds all the user fields like "password" in my model. How do I skip some fields like password from storing?

```
"detector": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "myUserModel",
      "property": "username",
      "options": {
        "validate": false,
        "persistent": true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but I think you can use the combination of `scope` and `field` filter:

```
"detector": {
  "type": "embedsOne",
  "model": "myUserModel",
  "property": "username",
  "options": {
    "validate": false,
    "persistent": true
  },
  "scope": {
    "fields": {
      "password": false,
    }
  }
}
```

Probably you also need to add `"strictEmbeddedModels": true,` to your 
model json file, to make sure extra properties are not saved. I'm not sure if that helps.

Possibly if the above method failed in any way, you should use [`operation hooks`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html) or [`remote hooks`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html) to clear the fields you don't want.